# TypeError: Error #1009 - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

**I'm getting this error:**

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Lemonade_fla::MainTimeline/frame3()[Lemonade_fla.MainTimeline::frame3:48]
```

**From this snippet of code:**

```
buy_sugar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buysugar);
function buysugar(event:MouseEvent):void{
    if (cash1>=0.50){
        buy.play();
        cash1 = cash.text.text;
        cash1 = cash1 - 0.25;
        sugar = sugar_count.text;
        sugar=sugar+16;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas of why?

Comment: Which of those is line 48?  When you find line 48, one of those objects on it will be null.  Of the 10 lines of code you've listed, that could possibly be...  buy_sugar, buy, cash, cash.text, or sugar_count.

Comment: then buy_sugar is null.  Is it a movieclip that you believe to be on the timeline when you call buy_sugar.addEventListener?

Comment: Yes, it's a movieclip with the instance name buy_sugar. Why?

Comment: It's not actually there when you're calling buy_sugar.addEventListener.  That's the problem.  Try this on the line right above the call to addEventListener ...  trace(buy_sugar);

Comment: It traced as "null". What does this mean?

Comment: It means that buy_sugar doesn't exist when you try to do something with it.  Are you SURE buy_sugar exists on frame 3?  It *has* to exist on the same frame as that timeline script.  I think we have enough information for an answer.  See mine below.

Comment: Does the name of the object, as in the library name, not the instance name, have to be buy_sugar or vice versa? Because buy_sugar is the instance name not the library name.

Comment: It's the instance name that's important.  The library name doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the commentary in the opening question, it seems that buy_sugar is null.  You believe that buy_sugar is a movieclip on the timeline, and thus can be safely referenced in your code, but if buy_sugar really existed you wouldn't get this error.

Are you absolutely positive that buy_sugar exists on the same frame as the call you're making?

Let's say you're currently on frame 3...

```
buy_sugar.addEventListener(Event.FOO, onFoo); // if buy_sugar exists on frame 3, this works.
```

But what if you're on frame 2?

```
gotoAndStop(3);
buy_sugar.addEventListener(Event.FOO, onFoo); // problem... this can fail if buy_sugar exists on 3 but NOT on 2.
```

Make sure that the clip you're referencing actually exists on the frame in which the call is written, and double-check your instance name spelling.

EDIT::

Those pictures are pretty interesting.  It does appear that buy_sugar is a movieclip symbol that exists on frame 3, yet buy_sugar traces as null in your frame 3 script.  Here are a few suggestions for further debugging.

1. In the code where you have trace(buy_sugar);, replace it with
   trace("testing buy_sugar presence ", buy_sugar, currentFrame);
2. CUT the buy_sugar movieclip from its place on the stage.  Make a new layer below all the others, and paste buy_sugar into the keyframe on frame 1.  Don't add ANY other keyframes on that layer.  The goal is to make sure the buy_sugar exists at all times, on all frames.

   Let me know what you see when you do this.

EDIT

Now that we've determined that the clip *can* be detected when it exists on all frames, scoot that keyframe over from 1 to 3 so that the clip exists only on frame 3.  Does it still work?  If so, just move that layer around to where it will look nicest.

If it does not work, again move that layer up to where the movieclip will look nicest.  Instead of putting the clip *only* on frame 3, make a keyframe on frame 3 with the clip where you want it, and on all other frames have the clip live somewhere off the visible stage.  That's kind of hacky, but it works to solve the problem.

Comment: I am sure that I'm on the same frame as of when the instance name is used with the event listener. I can take pictures if you want and show you.

Comment: @scriptocalypse did you view the images yet?

Comment: @Noah Rainey Yeah, I'm looking over them.  That's a pretty interesting scenario you've got here.  I'm having a think on this one and will update the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @Noah Rainey - I edited the answer.  Try those two steps and tell me what happens.  (Not expecting this to cure the issue, but maybe to give a few more clues)

Comment: Alright did what you said... the outcome: testing buy_sugar presence  [object sugar_1] 3
So what does this mean now? Also, I didn't receive an error.

Comment: Very bizarre.  Updating my answer in a minute.

Comment: I know, and this wasn't the first time things like this have happened.

Comment: Congratulations on that at least. :)  I'm out for the day.

Comment: Alright, thanks. However, I did do a flash player update. So that could have played a role in fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that:

1. "buy" object is not created
2. "cash" object is not created
3. "cash.text" is not created

You can try this:

```
if(buy)
    buy.play();
else
    trace("buy object is null");

if(cash && cash.text)
    cash1 = cash.text.text;
else
    trace("cash object is null");
```

Could you be more detailed?

Comment: It's acutally buy_sugar that's null, not any of the objects in the handler (or at least, if they are null they're not the ones responsible for this particular error)

Comment: Cash1 is created. I have other functions interacting with the variable. It's not that. And buy.play(0 works with the other functions as well. I've also copied the structure of the other functions to this function so there should be no differences besides the names. I've also checked spelling and syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

One of the items is not yet defined (or privately defined somewhere else).

Assuming this is the right code snippet, it's either buy, cash, cash.text, or sugar_count, because those are the objects where you try to access a property or method with dot syntax (.).